# How to access freebsd zfs partition under Linux using zfs-fuse?

Tags: linux, freebsd, zfs, fuse

I have installed dual OSs on my PC box: Linux and FreeBSD. The FreeBSD is installed on a ZFS partion under /dev/sdb1. Under Linux, the `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` outputs

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1        4981    40009851   a5  FreeBSD
/dev/sdb2            4982      121601   936750119+   5  Extended
/dev/sdb5            4982      121450   935537211   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6          121451      121601     1212876   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

`/dev/sdb1` is using ZFS. How to access it using zfs-fuse under Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interesting question here are ZFS Versions actually. it is impossible to mount ZFS Versions lower than the current one, as well as it is impossible to downgrade ZFS Pools.
While FreeBSD 9 is currently at ZFS Version 28, ZFS-Fuse is not! Afaik ZFS-FUSE is at ZFS Veriosn 16.

```
zpool upgrade -v
```

will AFAIK print your current ZFS Version on FreeBSD. If it is newer than 16, you must wait for a new ZFS-Fuse, that will support your ZFS Version.

When that is out of the way, do as @Mike Fitzpatrick wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Try `zpool import` to see a list of zpool candidates for importing, then `zpool import pool-name`. You may need to use the `-f` option to force the import if you didn't do `zpool export pool-name` from FreeBSD prior to rebooting into Linux.

Comment: I think, I first need to start FreeBSD in order to get the pool-name. Then, using `zpool import -f pool-name` under Linux. Did I get it? Is there a way to get the pool name without restarting the computer? I execute `zpool import` under linux and get nothing.

Comment: @Exaos, running `zpool import` without supplying a name will list any pools that ZFS is able to import. That's how to get the pool name. Then run the command again with the pool name to actually do the import. If you don't get any pools listed then you might have a configuration problem.